# How to model a category tree with relational databases

Tags: mysql, sql

Let's say there's a company that organizes events. For each event, I am interested in the type of music and the menu offered. For example:

Event 1; music: salsa; menu: menu1

Event 2; music: bachata, salsa, mariachi; menu: menu1, bar & grill

Event 3; music: mariachi; menu: bar& grill

Event 4; music: salsa, bachata; menu: menu2

....

The way I would intuitively implement this is by using a table as follow:

[image]

I don't know if this is the way to do it or maybe I should create two separate tables, one for each  category. How do you normally model this? I am about to learn how to implement it in MySQL and be able to retrieve the information for each event.

Answer (score 1):

No, that is not the way to do it.  You want to have one table that is an events table with an event id and other information -- say the location, date, contact person.

Then you want two table to represent the other relationships.

`event_music` has `event_id` and either the music name or a `music_id` (if you have another lookup table).

`event_menu` has information about the menus on offer.